# L3110 printer installation?

Tags: drivers

I have an epson L3110 printer and I want to install it on my Operating system:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Release: 18.04 Codename: bionic

Can you help me how is the procedure to install?

Answer (score 1):

Linux uses `CUPS`, the Common Unix Printing System. It's most easily configured by pointing your browser to `http://localhost:631/admin` (Use your login userid and password when prompted). You should see:  [image: CUPS admin page]

Click on `Find New Printers`

You may also find help at `https://www.cups.org/` or `https://epson.com/Support/wa00821`